# Angle between slanting edges of pyramid P and its base confusion..

Tags: geometry

[image]

What we normally do when we find the angle between a slanting edge and a pyramid is find angle PQE, or PAE.

But why is angle BAE $\neq$ PQE or PAE?

Line AB is also a side of a square base ABCD and AE is part of a slanting edge.
It seems odd to me. The angle must be the same?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Note that angles $PQE$ and $PAE$ aren't equal either.  In particular, $\tan(PQE)=EP/PQ$ and $\tan(PAE)=EP/PA$, but $PA > PQ$, and hence $\tan(PAE) < \tan(PQE)$.

Comment: @JimBelk you are right! I really suck at geometry.. I don't seem to have intuition for it. Everytime there is a question on geometry I get confused.. cyclic quadrilateral properties, maximum volume of circle of a pyramid and etc.. Is there a good book I can use to enhance this intuition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the height of the pyramid is very small. Then $\angle PQE$ and $\angle PAE$ each go toward 0 (though not at the same rate), whereas $\angle BAE$ goes towards $45^\circ$.

Comment: I didn't see that... thank you geometry really confuses me..!